# After first comma in CSV string, unable to escape any future commas in c#

Tags: c#, .net, csv, escaping

I am having a hard time escaping the commas in a string that I am writing to a csv file using the System.IO.File library's "WriteAllText" Method.  It seems like after using a comma once without escaping it, I can no longer escape a comma later on in the string.

```
using System.IO;
...
var test = "test, \"test,test\"";
File.WriteAllText(outputPath, test);
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

The expected output should look like this:

[image]

Comment: It is due to the quote in your string, it still finds the comma in the quotes and separates, then the rest of the line will be broken from a CSV perspective. Generally you want to replace all commas coming from your data prior to writing a CSV as it will negatively impact the results.

Comment: In short: get rid of the spaces between fields: http://superuser.com/questions/309122/importing-csv-into-excel-with-commas-in-quoted-fields

Comment: Thanks a bunch @TyCobb that did the trick! This was bugging me for a while! var test = "test, \"test,test\""; was changed to var test = "test,\"test,test\""; And it works great.  If you want to add this comment as an answer I would love to accept it!

Comment: You should read the docs about CSV https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180 will keep you away from a lot of pain